# How to start a big new ZF2 project?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am going to create a new project with ZF2 . In fact I'll have to upgrade a project ZF1 but I decided to start from scratch.

My project is very large and has already been translated into 10 different languages ​​by volunteers from all parts of the world.

The difficulty I am having is the analysis of the structure of the modules that ZF2 tells me to follow.

The software allows SMEs in the world of ISPs to manage their customer database , services, orders, invoices , domains , technical assistance , ecommerce, kb, and much more.

Assuming that ZF2 encourages programmers to create small modules reusable in other applications , and that in all cases we try to simplify and abstract as much as possible the structure of classes , many tables in the database of the project are connected to each other through various foreign keys and i can not understand how to create independent modules with their own files of entities and at the same time being disconnected from the project without causing a crash .

For example :

My application runs :

- Customers
- Orders
- Invoices
- Payments
- Messages
- Private Notes

Here is a screenshot of the web interface of the Project :
[image: ShineISP Orders Management]

As you can see the project shows as much as possible an overview of the law and order situation by embedding various sections of the same project . Initially I thought of creating a single module but I need some advice from you.

What strategy would you advise me to adopt a structure of a large project?

Comment: This question should be posted on `http://programmers.stackexchange.com`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I myself am currently working on a very large scale project in ZF2 and believe the key to success is embracing the modularity that the framework offers.

Some pointers I feel would be helpful :

- **Create an abstract/base module**

  Creating a "base" module will allow you to contain most of the shared/abstract interfaces/classes that could be used in any module. This will mean that the base module is a dependency of each other module within the system.
- **Modules have inter-dependencies**

  Some modules, although separated will depend on functionality of other modules (payments may need information on users for example).

  You should carefully think about what these services are and ensure that although they are shared, you do not start introducing coupling/code duplication in each module.

  I make extensive use of the `forward()` plugin, which allows me to call another controller action from within another and build a aggregated views, while still keeping each module encapsulated in their own modules.
- **An effective service layer**

  Really a general MVC design principle, however ensure you are not coding business logic within a controller but rather use 'service' classes injected into your controllers. If you don't you will quickly find it unmanageable.
- **Create Service Factories**

  Prefer concrete factory classes (classes implementing `Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface`) as apposed to closures otherwise you will quickly find that the number of factories you need will bloat your `Module.php` and these cannot be cached like the configuration - meaning a performance hit
- **ViewPlugins/Controller Plugins**

  Abuse the flexibility of controller and view plugins. These are extremely powerful ways to encapsulate and inject additional view/controller logic without having to extend existing classes.
- **Forms**

  Forms can be a pain as there is allot of dependencies that tend to need to be met. I think its essential to create reusable *fieldsets* that map directly to you domain model (entities). All the input filters/hydrators are then attached to this fieldset and should you wish to use them all you need to do is attach it to a form.

  If you have have a `CompanyFieldset` for instance, you could reuse it in `CompanyEditForm` and `CompanyCreateForm` and `CompanyEditForm`

An example from my project:

```
 class CompanyCreate extends EntityForm
 {
  public function init()
  {
    $this->add(array(
      'name'    => 'company',
      'type'    => 'Company\Form\CompanyFieldset', // <-- reused!!
      'options' => array(
        'use_as_base_fieldset' => true
      )
    ));
    // Only the button differs between forms!
    $this->add(array(
      'name'     => 'submit',
      'priority' => -100,
      'options'  => array(
        'skipLabel' => true,
      ),
      'attributes' => array(
        'type'  => 'submit',
        'class' => 'btn',
        'value' => 'Create'
      )
    ));
  }
}
```

In terms to your modules :

> My application runs: Customers, Orders, Invoices, Payments, Messages, Private Notes

This seems like a good list of self contained modules to begin with.

I'm sure there is more, i'll update if I can think of anything

Comment: Hi AlexP, thanks for your draft project but I don't see where you store the shared db entities. regards

Comment: @Michelangelo If a CategoryEntity requires a NewsEntity for example. usually your NewsModule would provide a NewsEntityInterface which then would be reusable by the CategoryModule to provide a NewsEntityInterface including a CategoryLinkInterface (or something like that). It's then up for configuration to not use NewsModule\Entity anymore but rather only CategoryModule\Entity in this case.

Comment: @Sam thanks for your message. Ok for the interfaces, but in my case the interfaces are a good choice for all the shareable modules and not for all the indipendent modules. am I clear?

Answer (score 3):

Modules can be a lot. And they can be barely anything at all. That's the charm of them. Try to not think overly complicated. Think of a `NewsModule` and a `CategoriesModule`. Think about gluing those two together. If you can manage that, a big project like yours will be just as simple. If you can not manage it, you'd better be advised to wait with starting your new project until you can do so.

Ultimately, big projects are always a mess. A mess in a sense that when you look at the first lines of code you write you'll feel shocked when you do so a year or two later. The ability to refactor code-segments is very important and that's precisely why you should separate the concerns of each of your modules as much as possible.

For a start, your "My application runs"-List appears to be a good first separation of independent Modules. The trick is to keep the interfaces simple so that adapters are easily interchangeable (Customer <-> Orders).

Comment: I need more information. I mean that I know how to handle a project but I don't find a clue between "Modules A" and its Entities and the "Module B" and its entities. As I wrote before I need to understand if there is a way to create and maintain the Customers Module easily. By the way thanks.