# Organization of a larger project in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

I need your advice with the organization site that is similar to facebook. I'm not sure how to organize modules for this type of site.

**My idea is to do the following modules:**

1. **Auth Module** ('user login, register, remember me, resert password, logout)
2. **Profile Module** (Add / Edit / Shows profile and cover images, izliztavanje your posts, information)
3. **Wall Module** (wall of the home page as FB, view status updates, like, add

4.**Upload Module** (upload images, videos)

5.**Group Module** (add, edit, delete group)

Is this okay? Can you give me some of your example.

Comment: You should check http://stackoverflow.com/a/21310868/949273

Comment: i will check. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't over complicate your design with lots of modules prematurely. Just because you can use lots of modules doesn't mean you should. There is nothing wrong with building one Application module initially. It's very easy to refactor things into their own module if/when you need to, but don't assume your modules need to be used for functional grouping or other organizational purposes. You can use namespaces within a single module to organize things.